# limitation to templates on RadListView

Tags: nativescript

I have a project in which i'll have to display different kinds of items in my `RadListView`, and it appears the total count of templates would be around 17. 
Can that cause performance problems? Is there a limit?

Checked the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/multiple-templates) and it seems like a limitation is not mentioned

Here's an example of my `RadListView` html, it now contains 8 types of items, each has its own template. There should be round 9 more templates:

```
<RadListView row="1" (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)" backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" class="gridLayoutLayout" #myListView [items]="dataItems" 
selectionBehavior="None"
loadOnDemandMode="Auto" (loadMoreDataRequested)="onLoadMoreItemsRequested($event)"
>
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Label text="Nothing" color="#000"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_dummy" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*" [height]="item.dummy_height">

        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>             

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_1" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" rows="*" columns="*"> 
            <feed-next-course [data]="item"></feed-next-course>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_2" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
            <feed-lesson-canceled [data]="item"></feed-lesson-canceled>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_3" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
            <feed-exam [data]="item"></feed-exam>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_4" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
            <feed-daily-schedule [data]="item"></feed-daily-schedule>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_5" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*, auto" columns="*" class="feed-final-grade-cont" >   
            <feed-final-grade [data]="item"></feed-final-grade>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkTemplateKey="item_6" let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
            <feed-assignments-soon [data]="item"></feed-assignments-soon>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

</RadListView>
```

Comment: What sort of performance problem you are hitting, can you elaborate possibly with a sample.

Comment: @Manoj I edited and added a sample code , it works but I was wondering if adding 9 more templates would potentially harm performance